# Работа со словарями в Python (задание из викторины)

Tags: python, dict

Наткнулся на очень интересное задание по Python и вот его суть:
Дополните программный код, в котором функция count_simbols(word) возвращает словарь со следующей структурой - {<'символ_1'>:<количество_в_слове>, <'символ_2'>:<количество_в_слове>, ... и.т.д.}
или False если на вход подана не строка.

word - type str.
EXAMPLE OF input/output when using this function:

```
>>> print(count_simbols('abracadabra')) => {'a':5, 'r':2, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':1}
```

###################################################

```
def count_simbols(word):
   dict = {}
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....
   .....

   else:

   .....
   .....

#########
```

##########################################

Есть варианты строк кода, которые можно использовать и вставить их до блока else: шесть и после блока else: две! Не больше не меньше!!! строго: 6 и 2! только так.

Вот варианты строк кода, которые даются для использования в ответе:

```
1) return keys
 2) for n in str(word)
 3) for n in word
 4) if n in keys:
 5) dict[n] = 1
 6) return dict
 7) keys = dict.keys()
 8) return False
 9) if n is keys:
 10) print(False)
 11) dict[n] += 1
 12) if isinstance(word, str)
 13) if not isinstance(word, str)
```

---

Выберете вариант строки кода и вставьте его в соответствующее место в коде программы вместо точек "....."

---

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, вроде и просто и сломал себе голову и уложиться в 6 и 2 строки ну никак не могу.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.
Мой вариант:

```
def count_simbols(word):
    dict = {}

    if isinstance(word, str):
        keys = dict.keys()
        for n in word:
            dict[n] = 1
            if n in keys:
                dict[n] += 1
        return dict
    else:
        if not isinstance(word, str):
            return False

print(count_simbols("abracadabra"))
```

результат:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2}
```

вариант №2 (убрал лишний isinstance):

```
def count_simbols(word):
    dict = {}

    if isinstance(word, str):
        for n in word:
            dict[n] = 1
            keys = dict.keys()
            if n in keys:
                dict[n] += 1
            else:
                dict[n] = 1
        return dict

print(count_simbols("abracadabra"))
```

результат все равно один и тот же)))

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2}
```

я не могу понять что я делаю не так...

Решение:

```
def count_simbols(word):
    dict = {}

    if not isinstance(word, str):
        return False

    for n in word:
        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
    return dict

print(count_simbols("abracadabra"))
```

результат:

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'r': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: И в чём у вас сложность? Там всё линейно довольно решается. Учтите, что `if`-ов в коде будет несколько, нужно только сообразить, в каком порядке их расположить, чтобы удовлетворить требования. Приведите ваш вариант решения, который не удовлетворяет условию 6-2, возможно там просто нужно будет пару строк местами переставить. ;)  А вообще там можно и от обратного пойти - сначала выкинуть варианты, которые в коде точно не пригодятся, а потом конструировать из оставшегося.

Comment: Добавил код в вопросе выше. Это не 6 строк, но хоть как-то работает. Перепробовал уже все возможные варианты (может что-то упустил). В этом варианте из слова переданного в функцию создается dict_keys, который содержит только уникальные ключи (из букв), но значения присваиваются после `dict[n] += 1` два раза (снчала 1 потом 2) и далее итерация заканчивается.

Comment: Так. Теперь подумайте - нужны ли вам две проверки `isinstance`? Одной проверки достаточно. Ну и `if n in keys:` вы не совсем правильно используете, подумайте ещё. В общем, сначала сократите код до нужного кол-ва строк, а потом будете придумывать как сделать, чтобы `else` было на нужной строке. В общем-то если вы избавитесь от лишнего `isinstance` задача уже практически решится.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос (вариант №2). Можно еще подсказочку )))) Не получается)))

Comment: А вы не видите, что у вас два раза `dict[n] = 1`, один из которых лишний? Вы его перенесли, а на старом месте не убрали

Comment: А теперь поставьте *другой* вариант `isinstance` но в начало кода, вместо того, который там сейчас.  И вместе с `return`. И это уже всё решение.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Решение в вопросе (отредактировал). Да действительно забыл убрать лишний `dict[n] = 1`, ну и по `isinstance` очень дельное замечание. Спасибо.